# MPI Isend and Ireceive doesn't work

Tags: c, mpi, distributed-computing, send, barrier

I have a problem with using Isend and Ireceive. I am trying to send a message to all other processors and after that receiving the same kind of messages from other processors which permormed the same Isend method.

```
void msgs(int my_rank, int num_procs){
    int arrive_count = 1;
    int leave_count = 0;
    int i;
    bool b_req = true;
    MPI_Request req, req2;
    //Send to all other procs
    for(i=0; i<num_procs; i++){
        if(i != my_rank){
            MPI_Isend(&b_req,sizeof(bool),MPI_BYTE,i,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req);
        }
    }
    bool c_req;
    //Receive msgs from all other procs
    while(arrive_count != num_procs){              
        for(i=0; i<num_procs; i++){
            if(i != my_rank){     
                MPI_Irecv(&c_req,sizeof(bool),MPI_BYTE,i,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req2);              
                if(c_req){
                    c_req = false;
                    arrive_count ++;                
                }
                MPI_Request_free(&req2);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Done from rank: %d \n", my_rank);    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three issues with your snippet :

- you cannot use `MPI_BYTE` with a `bool`. The MPI standard allows you to use `MPI_C_BOOL` with a `_Bool`, an other option is to manually convert between `bool` and `byte` before transferring `MPI_BYTE`
- you do not use `MPI_Isend()` nor `MPI_Recv()` correctly. You should have an array of requests, call `MPI_Waitall()` at the end.
- you can either `MPI_Irecv()` all the remote peers in a first loop, and then `MPI_Test()` to see check whether the message has arrived in an other loop (note you will need an array of `c_req`), or have a single loop that `MPI_Iprobe()` and `MPI_Recv()` right after if a message has arrived (and that required a single `c_req`.

As a side note, and unless you are doing any processing in the `while` loop, you might want to consider collective operations such as `MPI_Alltoall()`.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me and fixed the problem!